# OpenGL Context Creation Failure

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to make an OpenGL context through the Win32 API, without a wrapper such as GLUT. I've done this many times before, but this time I get one of two errors; Sometimes when you exit the window, the application doesn't end, but then a few seconds later the applications ends with the following message in the debug window:

```
Palette watcher thread id 5100 possible deadlock with DLL unload, killing the palette watcher
Unable to open the palette watcher thread id 5100 for termination!
```

The second message is sometimes displayed when the window is closed out:

```
PostMessage to hwnd: 00120266 failed with error: 00000578
```

I have Googled this already, and one found person with a similar problem that seems to have stemmed from **SetupPixelFormat**. I have no idea what could be a causing this. I have ruled out all other code as the problem besides the OpenGL rendering context setup.

Here is my setup:

```
BOOL Win32Handler::CreateOpenGLContext(void)
{

int pixelFormat;
this->hdc = GetDC(this->windowHandle);

PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR PFD =
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
    32,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,0,0,0,
    24,
    8,
    0,
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0,0,0
};

pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(this->hdc,&PFD);
if(!SetPixelFormat(this->hdc,pixelFormat,&PFD)) return FALSE;

this->hglrc = wglCreateContext(this->hdc);
if(!this->hglrc) return FALSE;

if(!wglMakeCurrent(this->hdc,this->hglrc)) return FALSE;

glewExperimental = TRUE;
GLenum error = glewInit();

if(error != GLEW_OK) return FALSE;

return TRUE;
```

}

This function is called in my main method after the window is created.

I know the OpenGL Context is not created either because **SwapBuffers()** and **glClearColor()** don't seem to work.

Note that when I don't call the setup code, these errors don't occur.
Also these two seem to happen randomly, sometimes when I close the application one occurs but not the other. They have never both triggered at the same time.

Comment: Obvious question is are you sure `GetDC(this->windowHandle)` is returning with something valid? (ie is the windowhandle valid?). I am wondering if there is even a valid Device Context setup by this point? My opinion is that a bad DC could cause this.

Comment: Hmph. I just checked the windowHandle and it does seem to be invalid. I'm not sure how this is possible, because I just checked the value of windowHandle in the window creation function, and it is valid! The OpenGL setup call comes directly after the window setup.

Comment: I'd probably have to see a bit of the code that does window creation. You sure you set the windowHandle variable with the HWND from the creation? Something must be occurring in between creation and this function to cause that behavior. I gather that this is strictly C++/Win32(Along with Wrangler library) code (No MFC/ATL etc)? May I ask what compiler and Dev environment? You can always edit your question with more code if you desire.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for your help! I will post my window creation code above, but I actually figured it out. I moved the context creation function into the message loop under WM_CREATE. So after the window was created, I used the HWND passed into the message loop and replaced **windowHandle** with that HWND and it works fine now. This is strictly C++/Win32 in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: No need to post more code. I will post an actual answer to this that one must have a valid Device Context or undefined behavior will occur. One thing I do recommend is you make sure that if you do GetDC you need to do a corresponding ReleaseDC somewhere as well. I am glad you at least have got past this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code I can only guess that the Device Context and/or the Window Handle are invalid. Anything that takes a Device Context that is invalid can exhibit bizarre and undefined behavior including errors at program shut down.

Make sure the window handle is valid and you have a valid Device Context. And an important note: For every `GetDC` you should make sure there is a corresponding ReleaseDC.